# How to create a multi line textbox with like button which can be sorted based on likes

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to develep comment section like this website's stackoverflow “answer module” using asp.net in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566184/i-want-to-develep-comment-section-like-this-websites-stackoverflow-answer-modu)

I am using a multiline textbox. Any user can post some article or content in that textbox. But other users should be able to like it (**Like button**). So later it can be displayed based on number of likes (**Sorting**). How to do this?

Comment: Add a like button next to your text box. Are you using MVC?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `Article` or `Comment` class which stores a user article or comment. Then you can have a `LikeCount` property on that object which gets incremented everytime someone "likes" it. This will enable you to sort the list of articles/comments based on that property.

Comment: K thanks..But am new to programming..I can understand what you are saying..But it is bit complicated for me to code that..Can u plz explain with little coding..